# Is Possible to update live data from from socket server to display data in client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

We want to send live data from the server which will automatically update on the client side. They Perform only display the data for the first time. If we have some changes in that data they do not perform well. After refresh page changed data will be displayed on the page. How to automatically update page using socket.io.

**Server-side code:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user connected %s',socket.id);

    //Send a message after a timeout of 4seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        //socket.send('Sent a message 4seconds after connection!');
        socket.emit('testEvent', { description: ' A custom event from server named testEvent after 4 seconds!'} );
    }, 4000);
});

client-side code 

socket.on('testEvent', function(data){
    document.write(data.description);
});
```

Comment: You also need to add your client code

Comment: Probably setState is not called correctly (if the question is react specific at all).

Comment: updated my client side code..